# PHP - How to get httpful phar to work

Tags: php, phpstorm, phar, httpful

From http://phphttpclient.com I followed "Install option 1" and the first "quick snippet".

I end up with the following, with Request undefined.

[image]

[image]

Additionally, and perhaps relatedly, I am confused by the fact that one of the code samples says "$response = Request::get" and another says "$response = \Httpful\Request::get". Is the latter valid PHP?

I have PHP 5.6.7.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The docs have been updated to always include the namespace to avoid this confusion in the future, @cja.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `\Httpful\Request::get()` is valid PHP. It tells PHP that you're looking for the class `Request` in the namespace `Httpful`. More on namespaces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

The reason you *can* call `\Httpful\Request::get()`, but can't call `Request::get()` is namespace related. In your `index.php`, you're not defining a namespace. Therefor, PHP just looks for a class `Request` in the global space (when calling `Request::get()`). PHP does not check if there's a `Request` class in another namespace.

You can `use` (import) a class, that will prevent you from having to type the entire namespace everytime you want to use the `Request` class:

```
<?php

use Httpful\Request;
$request = Request::get()

# you can also rename the class if you have multiple Request classes
use Httpful\Request as Banana;
$request = Banana::get()
```

More on that subject: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 1):

I just followed the 'quick-hack' install suggested by the author and got the same result. I then used the fully qualified namespace and got it working.

as :

```
$response = \Httpful\Request::get($uri)->send(); // qualified namespace here
```

I'll stick to the hack while i kick the tires, then if i adopt the lib, i'll go the composer route (much much better imo).